# Initializing a matrix with a certain value in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, initialization

I have this matrix A of size 100x100. Now I have another vector Z=(1,24,5,80...) which has 100 elements. it is a column vector with 100 elements. Now for each row of the matrix A, I want its A(i,j) element to be 1 where i is the row from 1:100 and j is the column which is given by Z

So the elements that should be 1 should be 
1,1
2,24
3,5
4,80 
and so on

I know I can do it using a loop. But is there a direct simple way I mean one liner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to convert the values in `Z` to absolute indices in `A` using [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), and then use vector indexing:

```
idx = sub2ind(size(A), 1:numel(Z), Z);
A(idx) = 1;
```

or simply in a one-liner:

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), 1:numel(Z), Z)) = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

A matrix that has 100 non-zero elements out of 10000 (so only 1% non-zero) in total is best stored as sparse. Use the capability of matlab.

```
A = sparse(1:100,Z,1,100,100);
```

This is a nice, clean one-linear, that results in a matrix that will be stored more efficiently that a full matrix. It can still be used for matrix multiplies, and will be more efficient at that too. For example...

```
Z = randperm(100);
A = sparse(1:100,Z,1,100,100);

whos A

  Name        Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes
  A         100x100             2408  double    sparse
```

This is a reduction in memory of almost 40 to 1. And, while the matrix is actually rather small as these things go, it is still faster to use it as sparse.

```
B = rand(100);
timeit(@() B*A)
ans =
   4.5717e-05

Af = full(A);
timeit(@() B*Af)
ans =
   7.4452e-05
```

Had A been 1000x1000, the savings would have been even more significant.

If your goal is a full matrix, then you can use full to convert it to a full matrix, or accumarray is an option. And if you want to insert values into an existing array, then use sub2ind.

Comment: +1 because it's easier and faster, guess I'll delete mine answer now :p

Comment: +1: Forgot about `sparse`. **Edit**: surprisingly though, I timed `sub2ind` against `full(sparse(...))` for a 1000x1000 matrix, and `sub2ind` was faster by almost a factor of 20. Can you explain that?

Comment: also timed it, `sub2ind` is 5 times slower for me. Did you take into account the creation of `A` ie: `A=zeros(numel(Z))`? This is needed, otherwise indexing into it is of no use..

Comment: @GuntherStruyf I didn't. Okay, now `sub2ind` is about the same order of magnitude (~95%), but still consistently faster than `full(sparse(...))`. What am I missing?

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that this solution is forcing the elements not included in `Z` to be zero. This is not required by the question and might possibly miss the OP's goal. It may just be that the OP wants to set certain elements  in `A` to 1, while the rest of the elements remain unchanged.

Comment: OP's talking about initializing a matrix, usually there's nothing in it at that moment. Timing stuff in matlab isn't an exact science, memory allocation can hurt a lot. But enough rambling now, we're taking this way to far :p